# conditional data table column sum in R

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data frame as below:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0), X2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1), X3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 1), Val = c(2, 3, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I want to create an output data frame with columns same as above data frame (except column 'Val')

Now, for each of the columns (X1, X2 and X3),

a) Column X1 => Find difference in 'Val' sum  when X1 = 1 and X1=0. For example, there are 2 rows when X1=1 and the 'Val' sum = 2+4 = 6
Similarly, there are again 2 rows when X1=0 and 'Val' sum = 3+5=8
The output data frame will have value = 6-8 = -2 under column 'X1'

b) Column X2 => 'Val' sum when X2=1 => 3+4+5=12 and 'Val' sum when X2=0 => 2. The output data frame will have 12-2=10 under column 'X2'

Similarly, for Column 'X3'

The output data frame will look like

```
structure(list(X1 = -2, X2 = 10, X3 = -4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Can we look for some data table solution here ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the zeros with negative ones and then multiply those columns by the val column and sum each column using apply.

```
df = as.data.table(df)

df[df == 0] = -1
df = df[, !"Val"] * df$Val
apply(df,2, sum)
# X1 X2 X3 
# -2 10 -4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   summarise(across(starts_with('X'), ~ sum(Val[. == 1]) - sum(Val[!.])))
#  X1 X2 X3
#1 -2 10 -4
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(Val[x == 1]) - 
       sum(Val[!x])), .SDcols = patterns('^X\\d+$')]
#   X1 X2 X3
#1: -2 10 -4
```